# Mongoose populate field of array field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, apollo

I have a collection users and a collection posts. Posts can have comments and these are stored in an array filed inside the post. I want to ref to these comments from a user, so the User should get the posts he posted and the comments he did.

When I query getMe() I can access the posts but I can't access the comments.
My question is how to store and access the comments on a better way?

My model looks like

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    post: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Post",
        },
    ],
    comments: [
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Post",
    ],
});

const postSchema = new Schema({
    body: String,
    comments: [
        {
            body: String,
            postedBy: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "User",
            },
        },
    ],
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
    },
});
```

The way I am adding a post and comment:

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: user.id },
      { $push: { post: newPost._id } }
).catch((err) => new Error(err));

await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: user.id },
      { $push: { comments: lastCommendId } }
).catch((err) => new Error(err));
```

The way I want to access the stored posts and comments:

```
Query: {
        async getMe(_, __, context) {
            const userContext = checkAuth(context);

            const user = await User.findOne({ _id: userContext.id }).populate(
                "post"
            )
            .populate("comments")

            return {
                id: user._id,
                post: user.post,
                comments: user.comments,
            };
        },
    },
```

Comment: You won't be able to use native mongoose populate for this. One solution would be to bring out comments into their own collection, which then you could use `populate`. This is also more scalable if you can have hundreds of comments. 

Another solution would be to write an aggregation that queries for all the comments a given user made. This would be roughly like `const comments = await Posts.aggregate([{$unwind: comments}, {$match: {postedBy: userId}}])`.